# Ubuntu 23.04 GNOME system settings close automatically

Tags: gnome, system-settings, 23.04

Whenever I am trying to access the GNOME system setting from UI, it does not open and when accessed from terminal
`gnome-control-center`
I get the below error:

```
23:01:19.2136       GStreamer-Play[231069]:   ERROR: GtkGstPlay: 'playbin' element not found, please check your setup
[1]    231069 trace trap (core dumped)  gnome-control-center
```

Using `sudo gnome-control-center` opens the setting but actually does not detects any hardwares such as bluetooth, monitor etc.

I've tried
`dconf reset -f /org/gnome`
the error gets resolved for few seconds and then once setting is opened from the UI, it gets closed within few seconds.

So far I've tried below commands but the error remains the same:

`sudo apt-get reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

`sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data`